# Java Regular Expressions Special characters and the & sign

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression that searches for all uppercase words but I need a regular expression that will search for special characters and the "&" Character. For example I would need a regular expression that would find words like "A&E" or "A/V".  Below is my standard Regular Expression for all uppercase words.

```
String twoPlusUCRegEx = "[A-Z][A-Z]+\\s";
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the java regular expression documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Just include the special characters you want in the second `[A-Z]` category. For example:

```
"[A-Z][A-Z&/]+\\s"
```

If you want all US-ASCII punctuation, you can use a POSIX character class:

```
"[A-Z][A-Z\p{Punct}]+\\s"
```

You might also want to put a word boundary or the like at the start of your r.e., so you don't match strings like "aAB".

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I'm rolling back your edit. In Java, some of the `\p{...}` character classes (including `\p{Punct}`) are specifically POSIX and work only for US-ASCII, not Unicode. See [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Comment: Hey Tim how would you do a word boundary?

Comment: Sorry I forgot...Ignore my last question